# Dividing the sets into two equal sum sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given two integers $a < = b$, we want to find whether there is a way to **split** set $\{a,a + 1,a + 2,\ldots,b-1,b\}$ into two sets of equal sum.

I want to find a necessary as well as sufficient condition for this.

**Observation:** Such a split is possible if  $(a+b)(b-a+1)/2$ is divisible by $2$.

The above observation can be proved very easily.

There are two cases now $(a+b)$ is divisible by $4$ or $(b-a +1)$ is divisble by $2$.

If $(b-a + 1)$ is divisible by $4$ then I can prove that there is a split.

**Question :** If $(a+b)$ is divisibly by $4$ then there is a split.

Comment: How about $\{2\}$? Then $(a+b)(b-a+1)/2=4\cdot \frac12=2$, which is divisible by $2$, but $\{2\}$ cannot be split into two sets of equal sum. You also state "The above observation can be proved very easily", yet here you ask for clarification...

Comment: @Vsotvep Thanks I have edited the question as per your observation.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression $(a+b)(b-a+1)/2$ is the sum of numbers in the set.  It needs to be even for there to be a split.  Note that $a+b$ and $b-a+1$ are of opposite parity, so the sum of numbers will be even precisely when one of the two factors is divisible by $4$.

This condition is necessary, but not sufficient.  As Vsotvep comments, if $b=a$ your set is a singleton there is no solution (unless the set is $\{0\}$).  Similarly if $b=a+1$ or $b=a+2$ there will be no solution except for $\{1,2,3\}, \{-1,0,1\},$ and $\{-3,-2,-1\}$.  If $b-a+1,$ the number of numbers in the set, is divisble by $4$ there will always be a solution because you can separate the set into pairs with the same sum and there are an even number of pairs.  If $a+b$ is divisible by $4$ there will be an odd number of numbers in the set.  The numbers need to be small enough and numerous enough to overcome the fact that one of your subsets will have more numbers in it than the other.  $a=1,b=7$ sums to $28$ and you can split it into $\{1,6,7\}$ and $\{2,3,4,5\}$ among other ways.  $a=9,b=15$ sums to $84$ and you can barely get away with $\{9,10,11,12\},\{13,14,15\}$.  $a=11,b=17$ fails.  I haven't worked to find a clean statement of when this will work.